# how to use snarkjs for NEAR protocol. how to make ZK prover/verify function in NEAR protocol with typescript?

Tags: zksnark, rollups, zero-knowledge, l2, near

i wanna make ZK-rollup whose L1 layer will be NEAR protocol.
what's the way to make Verifier function in Typescript of NEAR protocol ?

This function is not working:-

```
import { NearBindgen, view } from "near-sdk-js"; // , call,initialize
import {groth16} from 'snarkjs';

@NearBindgen({})
class ZKRollup {
    @view({})
    verifyProof(proof: string, publicInputs: string[]): boolean {
        // Parse the proof and public inputs from strings
        const parsedProof = JSON.parse(proof);
        const parsedPublicInputs = publicInputs.map((input) => BigInt(input));

        // Verify the proof using snarkjs
        const result = groth16.verify(
            parsedProof.vk,
            parsedPublicInputs,
            parsedProof.pi
        );

        // Return the result
        return result;
    }
}
```